How many orders does a big exchange receive in a trading day?
How many orders does a big exchange receive in one trading day in their most traded asset?
E.g. how many orders does Nasdaq receive for AAPL in one day?
I am interested in a rough estimation and can't really find those numbers anywhere. I can only find the number of trades, but especially with the presence of market makers there are certainly much more orders that remain untraded?

https://youtu.be/b1e4t2k2KJY?si=yxZVZLmsIIT0iM7I&t=220 at 3:40 guy says jane street receives 3M messages per second
